# Can you use Global chat while in a match?

Tags: blacklight-retribution

Is there a way to watch/talk in Global chat while you're in a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the Global chat by going to the menu "Esc" and picking the "global tab" in the social menu, top right.

But you can not see the contents of the chat during gameplay, that is reserved for the lobby chat, so every time you want to take a look at the Global chat you cant move while you are doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the chat commands: If you prefix your message with `/l` it will go to the Lobby. Type `/help` for a list. `/w NAME` will whisper, etc :).

Ex. `/l Hello everyone in the Lobby` or `/w Aceofgods Hello!`